# MP critical point has morse index 1

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-topology, nonlinear-analysis

I wonder where can I find a proof of the following fact: **if the mountain pass critical point is non-degenerate, then its Morse index is 1**. I am very interested in reading it.
In general, I am interested in reading notes on Morse index and MP critical points. So I will be very grateful, if someone can suggest me some notes about that.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Your terminology is evocative, but not mathematically precise. Can you give us your source for the terminology "mountain pass critical point"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem